# Can I take the derivative of a variable in sympy? Not the derivative of a function w.r.t a variable

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

Im trying to simplify a differential expression. If I take the derivative of x(t), `sympy.diff` returns dx(t)/dt. I just want dx(t). Heres the code im working with:

```
x  = Function('x',   real=True)(t)     
y  = Function('y',   real=True)(t)  
expr = x*y    # the expr im working with is more complicated actually, hence I need sympy to do it
simplify(diff(expr))
```

This returns

```
x(t)*dy(t)/dt + y(t)*dx(t)/dt
```

Sympy implemented the chain rule correctly. But I dont want it w.r.t the variable t. I want a function that can return simply:

```
xdy + ydx
```

Comment: the desired output is a _differential form_

Comment: I am not a sympy guru but I think the problem is your math level: `xdy + xdx` is a (mathematical) object which lives in the cotangent bundle which is spanned by the basis `dx`and `dy`. As it is now you are working with `t`-value parametrization of the the coordinate functions `x` and `y`.

Comment: here a [link](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/diffgeom.html) from the doc about _differential geometry_ tools